# Can we list all the orthonormal bases of $C[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, orthonormal

Let $C[0,1]$ denote the set of all real valued continuous functions over $[0,1]$. Can we list all the orthonormal bases of $C[0,1]$? In particular my interest to know that does there exist any basis involving exponential functions or hyperbolic functions?

Comment: You should first define the inner product. $\langle f,g\rangle= \int_0^1 fg\,dx$?

Answer (score 0):

In general no. Every vector space has a basis, but it's not always possible to write it explicitly assuming the axiom of choice. Consider spaces like
$C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^p([0,b]^2)$.

What's particularly interesting is that we do have bases for familiar spaces, but even without the knowledge that exotic function spaces "exist", we know *a priori* that we might not be able to find an explicit basis.

Comment: The question is not looking for Hamel-Basis, but for an ONB. Which doesn't make so much sense since I don't know any scalar product that makes $C[0,1]$ complete.